# AttributeError: module 'cx_Oracle' has no attribute 'errors'

Tags: database, postgresql, oracle, database-migration

I am migrating database schema from PostgreSQL to Oracle, and while doing this I am getting this error.

except cx_Oracle.errors.DatabaseError as e:
AttributeError: module 'cx_Oracle' has no attribute 'errors'. Did you mean: 'Error'?

This error is in this try catch block of code in the migrator.py file.

```
        def make_ora_connection(self):
    try:
        self.logger.info('Making Oracle connection...')
        self.ora_conn = cx_Oracle.connect(self.source_dsn)
        self.logger.info('Oracle Connection Successful...')

    except cx_Oracle.error.DatabaseError as e:
        self.logger.error(f"Error connecting to Oracle database: {e}")
        raise
    return AMTStatus.Success
```

[image]

I have checked the documentation of cx_Oracle to check if the error is because of the change in syntax, but I didn't find anything.
Can someone please have any idea about this.
Any help would greatly be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: As per the [doc](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/module.html#exceptions), it should be cx_Oracle.Error or cx_Oracle.DatabaseError